# Applying IF Condition on a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with three columns : `Subchannel`, `Campaign` and `ID`

```
Subchannel     Campaign       ID
PROMO          FLASHSALES     X123
PROMO          PERCENTOFF     Y123
```

I want to write a python code if the Subchannel starts with `"PRO"` then a new column should be created in the dataframe `EML_LOOKUP` with same values as Column `ID`. Below is the code that I was attempting but it doesnt work. Kindly help.

```
if  EML_LOOKUP['Subchannel'].str.startswith("PRO"):
   EML_LOOKUP['New_Column'] = EML_LOOKUP['ID']
```

Comment: `df['New'] = df['ID'].where(df['Subchannel'].str.startswith('PRO'))   `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where()` which works in a vectorized way and is faster than `apply()`:

```
import numpy as np 
EML_LOOKUP['New_Column'] = np.where(EML_LOOKUP['Subchannel'].str.startswith("PRO"),EML_LOOKUP['ID'],np.nan)
```

In this example, we're filling with `NaN` the new column if the Subchannel doesn't start with PRO, otherwise, we're setting the ID value.

Here's a full working example:

```
EML_LOOKUP = pd.DataFrame({'Subchannel':['PROMO','PROMO','NOT PROMO'],
                   'Campaign':['FALSHSALES','PERCENTOFF','REGULAR'],
                   'ID':['X123','Y123','Z123']})

  Subchannel    Campaign    ID
0      PROMO  FALSHSALES  X123
1      PROMO  PERCENTOFF  Y123
2  NOT PROMO     REGULAR  Z123
```

After applying the proposed solution:

```
EML_LOOKUP['New_Column'] = np.where(EML_LOOKUP['Subchannel'].str.startswith("PRO"),EML_LOOKUP['ID'],np.nan)
```

We get this output:

```
  Subchannel    Campaign    ID New_Column
0      PROMO  FALSHSALES  X123       X123
1      PROMO  PERCENTOFF  Y123       Y123
2  NOT PROMO     REGULAR  Z123        NaN
```

In case there are multiple conditions we can use add them separated by parenthesis and joined by the boolean operator `&` or `|` depending on the logic we desire to use:

```
EML_LOOKUP = pd.DataFrame({'Subchannel':['PROMO','PROMO','NOT PROMO'],
                       'Campaign':['FALSHSALES','PERCENTOFF','REGULAR'],
                       'ID':['X123','Y123','Z123'],
                       'Campaign':[10,3,20]})
EML_LOOKUP['New_Column'] = np.where((EML_LOOKUP['Subchannel'].str.startswith("PRO")) & 
                                    (EML_LOOKUP['Campaign'] > 5),
                                    EML_LOOKUP['ID'],np.nan)
```

Output:

```
  Subchannel  Campaign    ID New_Column
0      PROMO        10  X123       X123
1      PROMO         3  Y123        NaN
2  NOT PROMO        20  Z123        NaN
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough. It worked. Really appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if your question is solved! It will help with my reputation, too :)!

Comment: Hi Celius Stinger - If there would  have been multiple conditions, e.g. Subchannel starts with Pro and length of Campaign >5, how would I have used np.where condition? Please advise.

Comment: You would need to state each condition between parenthesis, and use the boolean operator `&`. Let me edit the answer

Comment: This is super helpful.You are brilliant. If you don't mind, can you please also answer, If I have to create two different new columns based on same condition and assign values to it, Is it possible through np.where?

Comment: Yes, you would need two lines of code, one for each new column

Answer (score 0):

Boolean indexing using your `str.startswith`:

```
EML_LOOKUP['New_Column'] = EML_LOOKUP['ID'][EML_LOOKUP['Subchannel'].str.startswith('PRO')]
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. This line of code gives me the error:The Error is : ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Comment: @Newbie123 There must be something else then.  Using the example DataFrame in Celius' answer, this works for me.  It's not doing the multiple condition thing, however (from your comments with Celius), but it could be modified to

Comment: Okay, thank you for looking into this. I will try again using your logic.Maybe some issue with the data that I have. The data that I have is not very clean.

Answer (score 0):

```
EML_LOOKUP['New_Column'] = EML_LOOKUP.loc[EML_LOOKUP['Subchannel'].str.startswith("PRO")].ID
```

Comment: Hi Vinod - How does using .loc helps? Does it means applicable to all rows?

Comment: Can you explain how this solves the problem or what this code does?

Comment: .loc filters data frame to a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array.  It will pick the row if the condition is `True`. Lets say for a particular row if the condition `EML_LOOKUP['Subchannel'].str.startswith("PRO")` is `True` that row is selected and similarly for all. Now for the group of selected rows, we have replicated `ID` column to `New_column`, replication applies to only the selected ones, and for non-seleted rows for `New_column` the value will be set to `NaN`.

Comment: This is a very helpful explanation. I tried this solution - Got an error - ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values. Should I replace the Na values with some string?

Comment: @Newbie123 Can you show your line of code exactly where you got the error.

Comment: The Error is : ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values and the line of code is what you suggested me.